# Want to create google sheet,docs ,folder using apps script for my google sites

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api, google-sites, google-drive-realtime-api

i want allow my users to create google drive docs,sheet,folders,files etc. from my google classic site itself.

i don't have any idea how to do this.Can we use google drive api?

if yes ,how to call drive api from apps script to create new google sheets,docs etc.

or

is there any other way to create it.

i want to use this in my google sites

Anybody have any idea please let me know

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be rather simple. Because you are working within Google Apps Script, you do not need to use the Drive API at all. You simply have to use the services made available to you by Google. Just read their documentation, like [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app). Right at the top, the first method clearly states `SpreadsheetApp.create(name)` will create a spreadsheet. Same thing with `DocumentApp.create(name)`, `FormApp` etc.